# Storing an X509 Certificate in a MySQL Database

Tags: ssl, x509certificate

We're working on a TCP server that secures its communication with its clients using TLS/SSL.

Currently we are storing our public (.cer file) and private (password protected, private key included .p12) certificates in the Windows certificate store. We are going to increase the number of TCP servers soon and depending on the traffic we'll be adding more and more in time.

To facilitate the deployment process and periodic certificate change (or in case we detect some sort of intrusion) we plan to store both (private and public) certificates in the system's common MySQL database that is accessible by the TCP servers.

Is storing the .cer and password protected .p12 files in BLOB columns a bad idea from a security point of view?

P.S: I don't think it is very relevant but the TCP server is being developed in c#.

Answer (score 0):

Skipping the security concerns, your language is PKE with native support for the windows store, you are going to have to roll your own (increase complexity) with this change. It would be better as part of the server start to update the Windows Store.

From a security point of view, you now have additional points where the encrypted key are accessible. Is you password secure enough? This is not a best practice and should be managed by the systems admin doing the install and updates. Lastly, this increase of complexity also increase the attack surface.